# DataSet to string w/ C# and AutoCAD .net API

Tags: c#, .net, api, autocad

I have a small group of functions that draws a schematic in AutoCAD using C#.

What I want to do is load an Excel spreadsheet in AutoCAD, then automatically draw the schematic and fill out the AutoCAD attributes from the Excel spreadsheet (pretty tricky).

I think my problem is getting the Data from the DataSet and incorporating it into table.Rows[i + 0] (in the DrawTest() function) or adding the proper code to the CommandMethod("CircuitArray") function, particularly the attRef.TextString =  "Hello World"; part. If I add text in between the "" on the attRef.TextString =  "Hello world"; part it will place the same text to the AutoCAD attributes of the schematic.

Spreadsheet Example:

[image: spread sheet example]

Circuit Example:

[image: circuit example]

```
public class MyCommands
{


      [CommandMethod("DrawTest")]
    public void DrawTest()
    {
        string Path = SelectSpreadsheet();
        System.Data.DataTable table = ReadExcelToTable(Path);
        InsertBlocks();
        AddIOmodule("AI-1756-IF16H-SHEET1");
        for (int i = 0;  i < 2; i++)
        {
            CircuitArray("AI-AIT-CIRCUIT", 25, 17-i, 0, table.Rows[i + 0]);
        }

    } 


[CommandMethod("LoadIOlist")]
    static public string SelectSpreadsheet()
    {
        Document doc =
          Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;
        OpenFileDialog ofd =
          new OpenFileDialog(
            "Select Excel spreadsheet to link",
            null,
            "xls; xlsx",
            "ExcelFileToLink",
            OpenFileDialog.OpenFileDialogFlags.DoNotTransferRemoteFiles
          );
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr =
          ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (dr != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            return null;
        ed.WriteMessage(
          "\nFile selected was \"{0}\".",
          ofd.Filename
        );
        return ofd.Filename;

    }   

 public static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelToTable(string path)
    { 
        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
        System.Data.DataSet set = new DataSet();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable sheetsName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "Table" });
            string firstSheetName = sheetsName.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheetName);
            OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connstring);
            ada.Fill(set);
            conn.Close();
        }
        return set.Tables[0];           
    }

 [CommandMethod("InsertBlocks")]
    public void InsertBlocks() // This method can have any name
    {
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        using (Database OpenDb = new Database(false, true))
        {
            OpenDb.ReadDwgFile("C:\\Users\\siewertb\\Documents\\CAD\\CADautomation\\IO-SCHEMATICS.dwg",
                System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, true, "");

            ObjectIdCollection ids = new ObjectIdCollection();
            using (Transaction tr =
                    OpenDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                //For example, Get the block by name
                BlockTable bt;
                bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(OpenDb.BlockTableId
                                               , OpenMode.ForRead);


                if (bt.Has("AI-1756-IF16H-SHEET1"))
                {
                    ids.Add(bt["AI-1756-IF16H-SHEET1"]);
                }

                if (bt.Has("AI-AIT-CIRCUIT"))
                {
                    ids.Add(bt["AI-AIT-CIRCUIT"]);
                }

                tr.Commit();
            }

            //if found, add the block
            if (ids.Count != 0)
            {
                //get the current drawing database
                Database destdb = doc.Database;

                IdMapping iMap = new IdMapping();
                destdb.WblockCloneObjects(ids, destdb.BlockTableId
                       , iMap, DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore, false);
            }
        }
    }

[CommandMethod("AddIOmodule")]
    static public void AddIOmodule(string name)
    {
        Database db = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction myT = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            //Get the block definition
            string blockName = name;
            BlockTable bt =
                db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord blockDef =
              bt[blockName].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            //Also open paper space - we'll be adding our BlockReference to it
            BlockTableRecord ps =
              bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)
                                                      as BlockTableRecord;
            //Create new BlockReference, and link it to our block definition
            Point3d point = new Point3d(32.03125, 20.34375, 0);
            using (BlockReference blockRef =
                    new BlockReference(point, blockDef.ObjectId))
            {
                //Add the block reference to paper space
                ps.AppendEntity(blockRef);
                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blockRef, true);
                //Iterate block definition to find all non-constant
                // AttributeDefinitions

            }
            //Our work here is done
            myT.Commit();
        }
    }

[CommandMethod("AddCircuit")]
    static public void AddCircuit(string name)
    {
        Database db = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction myT = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            //Get the block definition
            string blockName = name;
            BlockTable bt =
                db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord blockDef =
              bt[blockName].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            //Also open paper space - we'll be adding our BlockReference to it
            BlockTableRecord ps =
              bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)
                                                      as BlockTableRecord;
            //Create new BlockReference, and link it to our block definition
            Point3d point = new Point3d(25, 17.28125000, 0);
            using (BlockReference blockRef =
                    new BlockReference(point, blockDef.ObjectId))
            {
                //Add the block reference to modelspace
                ps.AppendEntity(blockRef);
                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blockRef, true);
                //Iterate block definition to find all non-constant
                // AttributeDefinitions
                foreach (ObjectId id in blockDef)
                {
                    DBObject obj = id.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    AttributeDefinition attDef = obj as AttributeDefinition;

                }
            }
            //Our work here is done
            myT.Commit();
        }

[CommandMethod("CircuitArray")]
    public void CircuitArray(string name, int x, int y, int z, DataRow row)
        {
        Database db = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction myT = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            //Get the block definition
            string blockName = name;
            BlockTable bt =
                db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord blockDef =
              bt[blockName].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            //Also open paper space - we'll be adding our BlockReference to it
            BlockTableRecord ps =
              bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)
                                                      as BlockTableRecord;
            //Create new BlockReference, and link it to our block definition
            Point3d point = new Point3d(x, y, z);

            using (BlockReference blockRef =
                    new BlockReference(point, blockDef.ObjectId))
            {
                //Add the block reference to paper space
                ps.AppendEntity(blockRef);
                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blockRef, true);

                //Iterate block definition to find all non-constant
                // AttributeDefinitions


                int count = 0;
                foreach (ObjectId id in blockDef)
                {
                    count++;
                    DBObject obj = id.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    AttributeDefinition attDef = obj as AttributeDefinition;
                    if ((attDef != null) && (!attDef.Constant))
                    {
                        //This is a non-constant AttributeDefinition
                        //Create a new AttributeReference
                        using (AttributeReference attRef = new AttributeReference())
                        {
                            attRef.SetAttributeFromBlock(attDef, blockRef.BlockTransform);
                            attRef.TextString =  "Hello World";
                            //Add the AttributeReference to the BlockReference
                            blockRef.AttributeCollection.AppendAttribute(attRef);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Our work here is done
            myT.Commit();
        }
```

Comment: My advice would be to really generalize your patterning here.  Make a routine that simply adds a block reference.  Maybe have it take parameters for the path and insertion point (if placing rather than loading).  Next you need a generic block editing routine (maybe pass in a dictionary for setting attribute values).  Then just leverage those for your specific task, and you end up with reusable code that's not entrenched into this one exact job.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think you're right, I may have to break up the routines into simple separate blocks. I am novice as heck with programming, but I guess I was thinking that since the block is inserted on an index starting at 0, then I could fill out that block's attributes (wire labels ect.) at row 0 or the first row of the table that correlates to that circuitry. I'll give your advice a try. I will have to learn how to use the dictionary aspect of this!

Comment: Hi Ben - what is the problem in the above code? i'm certain it can be done - i have managed to do the same thing but reading from an MS Acess database

Comment: I have been able to solve this problem. Now I am trying to map the objects (each circuit) to a row in an excel spreadsheet so that if that row is moved or deleted, then the circuit is moved or deleted. I'll post a new question for this part.